# How to get xml attribute with plsql?

Tags: xml, plsql

```
create table xtest01(col1 xmltype);
insert into xtest01 values ('<car><model>Audi TT</model></car>');
insert into xtest01 values ('<car model="BMW X5"/>');
```

-- I know how to get Audi TT:

```
select x.col1.extract('//car/model/text()').getStringVal() from xtest01 x;
```

-- But how to get BMW X5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select x.col1.extract('//car/@model').getStringVal() from xtest01 x;
```

Comment: thanks! (this is the answer; I can accept it after some minutes, as pop-up says to me)